# Converting Pandas dataframe of hex numbers to integers and floats and split it into single columns

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, type-conversion, hex

I would like to convert a pandas dataframe which contains space separated hex numbers into integers and floats (some columns only contain integers, some columns are floats). The dataframe has an index column (its a time variable).

The dataframe looks like this:

```
print(selected_df.XData)
DataSrvTime
2021-07-08T08:43:29.0616419     C7 10 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0...
2021-07-08T08:43:30.0866790     C2 16 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0...
2021-07-08T08:43:31.1107931     CB E 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
2021-07-08T08:43:32.1398927     BF 13 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0...
2021-07-08T08:43:33.1697282     BA 15 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0...
                                                     ...                        
2021-07-08T11:12:51.1695194     4 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0...
2021-07-08T11:12:52.2000730     5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0...
2021-07-08T11:12:53.2248873     4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0...
2021-07-08T11:12:54.2574457     2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0...
2021-07-08T11:12:56.3157504     6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0...
Name: XData, Length: 7799, dtype: object
```

First of all I split the dataset -each into an own column. The first character of the dataframe is a delimiter. I dismissed the first column therefor to only keep the data containing columns and add a column name:

```
# Defining the column names:
header = ["00","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","MTF1","MTF3","MTF5","MTF7","SP","SFR","T","RH","PM_1","PM_2","PM_3","#RG","#RL","#RR","#RC","LS","Checksum"] 

# split data into single columns
x_df = selected_df.XData.str.split(' ', expand=True)

# dismiss first delimiter column
x_df.drop(0, inplace=True, axis=1)

#add column names
x_df.columns = header
```

Now, I tried different ways to convert the hex data into integers and/or floats which all of them result in errors. Maybe anyone of you has an idea to make it better than me..

```
# Simply test apply solution without header yet:
res = x_df.apply(int, base = 16)
```

Results in this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-107-004c8b72cd04> in <module>
---> 39 res = x_df.apply(int, base = 16)

c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwargs)
   8831             kwargs=kwargs,
   8832         )
-> 8833         return op.apply().__finalize__(self, method="apply")
   8834 
   8835     def applymap(

c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply(self)
    725             return self.apply_raw()
    726 
--> 727         return self.apply_standard()
    728 
    729     def agg(self):

c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    849 
    850     def apply_standard(self):
--> 851         results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
    852 
    853         # wrap results

c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    865             for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
    866                 # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
--> 867                 results[i] = self.f(v)
    868                 if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
    869                     # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because

c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in f(x)
    136 
    137             def f(x):
--> 138                 return func(x, *args, **kwargs)
    139 
    140         else:

TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base
```

Doing a `print(x_df.dtypes)` shows that all columns are of "object" type.
I thougt that the `str.split` made already strings of the splitted columns?

Then, the resulting datatypes of the first 24 columns should be integer while the datatype of the rest is float - except of the last one, which is a simple checksum.

Do I have to solve that with a loop?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a semi-solution (integer values only in this step):

With a `for` loop I iterate through the columns (in this case I overwrite them; if not intented I could keep the original data and create a new dataframe with `manipulated = x_df.copy()` )

To avoid the error I got earlier I have to add the iteration variable to specify the current column:

```
# convert hex data to int
for column in x_df:
    x_df[column] = x_df[column].apply(int, base=16)
print(x_df)
```